# Webpack seems to ignore my typescript loader

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to use webpack to package my typescript project but it seems to ignore my loader settings.

Currently I have :

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry:{
        app: "./words.ts",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
                  {
                      test: '/\.ts?$/',
                      loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                      exclude: '/node-modules'
                  }
    ]
    },
    resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },

    output:{
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename:"[name].js"
    }
}
```

I know that it is using my `webpack.conf` file because if I remove it then it complains and it appears to work correctly but what I notice is that it does not matter what I put as the loader, for example if I put `"hello"` it will still transpile and package my code. I have also noticed that if I remove my `tsconfig.json` file I get the same result so it is clearly not trying to use it. Is there a default loader setup that I need to override?

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: There is no default loader for typescript, my suspicious is the regex, `test: '/\.ts?$/',` try to remove the `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing a string that contains the regex instead of regex as a `test` argument.

Try to change it to:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/, // this suppose to be regex expression.
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
    exclude: '/node-modules'
  }
]
```